# Transforming Observable into Observable which emits after doing animation

Tags: scala, rx-java

I am building a game using RxScala. I want to do an animation when the user dies and after that I want to return the user to the start position of the game.

I have a hot Observable positionObservable that emits the position of the user every time the user has moved.
To find out when a user dies I can use the following code:

```
positionObservable.filter(isDead)
```

using the function `die(points)` I can start an animation to let the user die. This function returns a new Observable which emits when the animation is done.
I was thinking about chaining these two into:

```
val gameLostObservable = positionObservable.filter(isDead).flatMap(points =>die(points))
```

But then the die function will never run when there are no subscribers and will run multiple times when there are multiple subscribers. I have also read that doing side effects in a transformer function is discouraged.

What is the best method to transform the original positionObservable to a new Observable that emits when the animation is done?

Comment: More details about `positionObservable`? As per your discription, `positionObservable` is cold. But looks it should be hot.

Comment: When would you have more than one or zero subscribers? Saving and subscribing to an observable multiple times is almost always not what you want unless you are using `.cache()`, `.publish()`, or using a `Subject`.